# UML which arrow to show when dealing with a "belongs to" relationship

Tags: java, uml

Which arrow would I use to show a 'belongs to' relationship for a UML diagram?

In this case, PersonalSavingAccount belongs to Person class, and it extends to SavingAccount class (which extends to BankAccount abstract class).

I know I do the solid line arrow head from PersonalSavingAccount to SavingAccount but what do I put to the Person class?

Anyone have an answer?

Comment: What do you mean accept the answers? How am I not accepting the answers?

Comment: Oh the checkmark. Okay. I'll do that now then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class diagram, a relationship between two classes is usually an association, which is a solid line between the two classes.

To indicate the semantics of the association, you can give it a name, e.g. "belongs to".

[image: cd1]

If you want to specify *how many* accounts a person may have and/or to *how many* persons an account may belong, you may add *multiplicities*, but this is not mandatory. In the example below, I have specified that a person may have zero or more accounts and that an account always belongs to one person.

[image: cd2]

Comment: Honestly naming an association "belongs to" is just a tautology.